# how to disable spring bean loading log

Tags: spring

How to disable spring log. When loading bean through xml its display spring log.
Is there is any way to disable spring log like this.
Is there is any server specific setting i am using Jboss?

[STDOUT] 13:13:55,765 INFO  [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/jboss-4.0.0/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp27157businesscaliber-exp.war/WEB-INF/businesscaliber-servlet.xml]
[STDOUT] 13:13:55,781 INFO  [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext] Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;hashCode=15981314]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory defining beans [dataSource,dao,contactUsDao,userDao,advertisementDao,businessDao,miscellaneousDao,contactusController,loginUser,userController,homeController,advertisementController,businessController,miscellaneousController,adminController,exceptionController,fileUploadController,captchaEngine,captchaService,imageEngine,CaptchaFactory,wordgen,filedict,wordtoimage,fontGenRandom,fontArial,backGenUni,simpleWhitePaster,colorGreen,captchaController,urlMapping,queries,multipartResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver]; root of BeanFactory hierarchy
[STDOUT] 13:13:55,781 INFO  [FileSystemXmlApplicationContext] 34 beans defined in application context [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;hashCode=15981314]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using log4j, you may turn off Spring logging in file log4j.properties (you may find it in WEB-INF folder). Just comment out all lines with `org.springframework` substring.

Comment: As per your comment , Now I used log4j.xml in /WEB-INF with default confuguration its working
Thanks Yuri

Thanks