# disable spring boot default logging to /var/logs/app.log

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j

I'm using the Spring Boot launch script and I am not setting LOG_FOLDER a value.
I have configured logs using log4j.xml and passing log folder path while running the application which is working fine.But logs are being written to /var/log folder.

How to disable the default logging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Spring log, to have readable logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648014/disabling-spring-log-to-have-readable-logs)

Comment: Its not log level.Its the log itself.

Comment: 1) /var/log is the default Log Folder location so it makes sense that spring assumes /var/log as log location as you have not explicitly overridden it. 2) what do you mean Passing log folder path while running the application works fine? - isn't it the problem you are facing?

Comment: I have my own custom log path .But spring boot application writes the log to default path /var/logs when you  run the application as service.
How can i disable the default logging.

Comment: ok, where did you set the custom log path?

Comment: Is that fixed @DushyanthNagaraju? If yes, Can you please share it?